# Проверка формы на кол-во символов JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, форма

Есть форма с логином и паролем. Поле с паролем закрыто и должно открыться после ввода 5 символов в поле с логином, а кнопка входа открыться после заполнения 5 символов в поле логина и пароля. Как это организовать на js (jquery)?

Answer (score 1):

**Можно так:**

```js
function checkCount() {
  
$("#password").attr("disabled", true)
$("#button").attr("disabled", true)

if ($("#login").val().length > 5) {
 $("#password").removeAttr("disabled")
   
 if ($("#password").val().length > 5) {
  $("#button").removeAttr("disabled")
 }
}
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Login" onkeydown="checkCount()" onkeyup="checkCount()">

<input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onkeydown="checkCount()" onkeyup="checkCount()" disabled="disabled">

<button id="button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('input', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 5) {
      $('input[type="password"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('input[type="password"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('input', 'input[type="password"]', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 5) {
      $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password" disabled>
  <input type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```